# Google Maps guided navigation for 1000 pickup points-(Bin collection)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am novice in programming but i have taken a massive undertaking. i am working on a project to create a guided navigation for the truck driver to collect bins from the customers. The number of customer in total would be more than 56000. there will be lots of different routes.

**things done so far:**
i have plotted x,y coordinate of the customers on a custom "my maps" to visually represent thew customer location.Now,i need a real time guided navigation to cover all the points on the given route.

i have started working on android studio and google maps sdk.
kindly guide me a way forward.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be more specific on what you are trying to do, do you want to find the shortest path? If so this is a rather complicated problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Comment: @LeoE yes, i would like the drivers to cover all the location in a shortest path possible. i have the data points(customer location x,y coordinates)

Comment: Have you had a look at the link? 56000 datapoints doesn't seem like it is feasible to be honest